# Javascript Reload Div Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to refresh a div via JavaScript. I can handle it but my structure is more complicated than that.

If user clicks a button a new div is appearing. After that, this div should reloaded every 3 seconds. These parts are OK. The problem is when the user clicks on another button the system reloads the old div. E.g. user clicks button Nr 1 first then it opens and starts to reload every 3 seconds. Then user clicks button Nr 2, it opens but button Nr 1's div reloading after 3 seconds.

You can find my code below:

```
function refreshDiv(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('canli'); ?>/' + id,
        type: "GET",
        data : "",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null)
                $("#matchDetails").html(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$('.livemenumatch').click(function() { 
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    localStorage.setItem("lastid", id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/modo/li/' + id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'submit': true },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#matchDetails").html(data);
        },
    }); 

    var lastid = localStorage.getItem('lastid', lastid);
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        refreshDiv(lastid)
    }, 3000);  
});
```

I tried to clear interval after button click but nothing changed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `refreshIntervalId` variable which holds the `interval` is set within the scope of the click handler. This means that when you click button #2 the variable holds nothing and the previous interval is not cleared. You need to declare the interval variable in a higher scope. Try this:

```
var refreshIntervalId; // delcare the variable here...

$('.livemenumatch').click(function() { 
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);

    // rest of your code... 

    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        refreshDiv(id)
    }, 3000);  
});
```

Note however that a better pattern to use instead of `setInterval()` is to call `setTimeout()` after each successful completion of the request. This means that should each request take longer than 3 seconds they won't get backed up and flood the server.

```
function refreshDiv() {
    var id = localStorage.getItem('lastid');
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('canli'); ?>/' + id,
        type: "GET",
        data : "",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null)
                $("#matchDetails").html(data);

            setTimeout(refreshDiv, 3000);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$('.livemenumatch').click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    localStorage.setItem('lastid', id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/modo/li/' + id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'submit': true },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#matchDetails").html(data);
        },
    });  
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I just updated my answer with a slightly better pattern for you.